# oracle sql full join with table a not in

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have to tables (tbla and tblb) with each one col (id):

select * from tbla;

```
ID
---
1
3
5#A

select * from tblb;

ID
---
2
3
```

Now I need a full join:

```
select a.id, b.id
from tbla a
full outer join tblb b on b.id = a.id;

ID  ID1
--------
1   
3   3
5#A 
    2
```

... but without entries containing a #-sign in tbla.id

```
select a.id, b.id
from tbla a
full outer join tblb b on b.id = a.id
where a.id not like '%#%';

ID  ID1
--------
1   
3   3
```

why is the entry with id 2 from tblb missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you do a `full outer join`, columns on either side can end up with a `NULL` value.

Explicitly check for NULL:

```
select a.id, b.id
from tbla a
full outer join tblb b on b.id = a.id
where a.id not like '%#%' or a.id is null;
```

(Originally, I had suggested moving the logic to the `on` clause.  Alas, the `full outer join` keeps records in both tables, even when no records match the condition.  So, moving the condition to the `on` clause doesn't fix anything.)

Comment: thanks, the second select works fine. the first one still contains 5#A

Answer (score 0):

When you do outer joins, you have to do your filtering in the from clause.  If you do it in the where clause your join effectively becomes an inner join.

So change this:

```
full outer join tblb b on b.id = a.id
where a.id not like '%#%'
```

to this

```
full outer join tblb b on b.id = a.id
and a.id not like '%#%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a full join, but by specifying a.id in the where clause, you filter your result set afterwards.

To achieve what you want, you can either move the clause into the join condition:

```
select a.id, b.id
from tbla a
full outer join tblb b 
  on b.id = a.id
  and a.id not like '%#%';
```

Or you can use nvl:

```
select a.id, b.id
from tbla a
full outer join tblb b on b.id = a.id
where nvl(a.id, 'n/a') not like '%#%';
```

Or explicitly allow NULL values for a.id:

```
select a.id, b.id
from tbla a
full outer join tblb b on b.id = a.id
where (a.id is null or a.id not like '%#%');
```